# How to generate a source file when building using autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

With Make, I do something like

```
generated.c: input.txt generator
    ./generator input.txt > generated.c
```

How would I get equivalent functionality out of autotools? (removing generated.c on cleaning would also be a bonus).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm assuming that `input.txt` is a source file that is distributed, that you do *not* want to distribute `generated.c` (i.e., it must be built by each user), and that `generator` is a program built by your package too.

```
EXTRA_DIST = input.txt
bin_PROGRAMS = prog
noinst_PROGRAMS = generator

# Source files for the generator
generator_SOURCES = generator.c ...

# Source files for prog
prog_SOURCES = prog.c ...
nodist_prog_SOURCES = generated.c 

# generated.c is a built source that must be cleaned
CLEANFILES = generated.c

# Build rule for generated.c
generated.c: $(srcdir)/input.txt generator$(EXEEXT)
        ./generator$(EXEEXT) $(srcdir)/input.txt
```

In some situations, like when generating header files, it is important to generate the file *before* the rest of the sources are compiled, so it can be included.  In that case you should also list the generated file in the variable `BUILT_SOURCES` (The Automake manual has many example in its [Built sources section](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/automake/Sources.html).  In the above case it is not necessary.

**EDIT**: I have fixed the above `Makefile.am` example to declare `generator` as a non-installed program.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for, and references to read more, too!

Comment: I have a [follow-on question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327461/automake-generated-source-files-and-vpath-builds) for this, regarding how to make this work for VPATH builds.

Comment: @Craig Answered.  HTH.