# Generating variable name source files when building with autotools

Tags: makefile, code-generation, autotools, autoconf, automake

This question builds upon [How to generate a source file when building using autotools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284918/how-to-generate-a-source-file-when-building-using-autotools)

I want to do something like

```
<generated-c-files>: input.txt generator
    ./generator input.txt      # produces <generated-c-files>
```

The earlier question answers this scenario when the generated c file(s) have fixed name(s) known a priori. However, I have a variable number of files with variable names being generated, depending on the contents of input.txt. What is a good way to do it with autotools?

I am using wildcards to pick up all generated files, which are being placed in a single build folder. However, this requires me to `make` twice, where the first `make` fails to link. This seems to be because the wildcard is evaluated before `generator` is executed. I would like to do it with one successful `make` and, preferably, not use wildcards.

Comment: Do the generated files have a common patternt or anything?

Comment: If the output files differ from the inputs in extension only, then a suffix rule can be used. General pattern rules are a GNU extension.

Comment: You cannot use a pattern or suffix rule if the target files do not exist, and the list of preqrequisite files is not known.  For instance, suppose you don't know what C sources make up the C program. If the .o files all exist from a previous build, then you can infer that the program is made up of all the .o's, and for each .o you can infer that the corresponding .c is a prerequisite. However, when the .o files do not exist (clean (re-)build), oops!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that since the responsibility for parsing `input.txt` is encapsulated within `generator`, it is `generator` which can tell you what files are to be generated. It should have some options for that, so you can do stuff like, for instance:

```
GENERATED_C_FILES := $(shell ./generator --list-output-files input.txt)

# We don't list generator as a prerequisite here because it has to exist
# for the above to work.

$(GENERATED_C_FILES): input.txt
    ./generator input.txt
```

There are hacks that can be done to get `make` to detect that `generator` is missing, rebuild it, and re-run itself. But, more simply and clearly, maybe the `generator` build-time utility can be produced at `./configure` time, so that it can be relied upon to be there at `make` time.