# Automake, generated source files and VPATH builds

Tags: code-generation, swig, automake, vpath

I'm doing VPATH builds with automake. I'm now also using generated source, with SWIG. I've got rules in `Makefile.am` like:

```
dist_noinst_DATA = whatever.swig

whatever.cpp: whatever.swig
    swig -c++ -php $^
```

Then the file gets used later:

```
myprogram_SOURCES = ... whatever.cpp
```

It works fine when `$builddir == $srcdir`. But when doing VPATH builds (e.g. `mkdir build; cd build; ../configure; make`), I get error messages about missing `whatever.cpp`.

Should generated source files go to `$builddir` or `$srcdir`? (I reckon probably `$builddir`.)

How should dependencies and rules be specified to put generated files in the right place?

Answer (score 3):

### Simple answer

You should assume that `$srcdir` is a read-only, so you *must not* write anything there.
So, your generated source-code will end up in `$(builddir)`.

By default, autotool-generated Makefiles will only look for source-files in `$srcdir`, so you have to tell it to check `$builddir` as well. Adding the following to your `Makefile.am` should help:

```
VPATH = $(srcdir) $(builddir)
```

After that you might end up with a `no rule to make target ...` error, which you should be able to fix by updating your source-generating rule as in:

```
$(builddir)/whatever.cpp: whatever.swig
        # ...
```

### A better solution

You might notice that in your current setup, the release tarball (as created by `make dist`) will contain the `whatever.cpp` file as part of your sources, since you added this file to the `myprogram_SOURCES`.
If you don't want this (e.g. because it might mean that the build-process will really take the pregenerated file rather than generating it again), you might want to use something like the following.
It uses a wrapper source-file (`whatever_includer.cpp`) that simply includes the generated file, and it uses `-I$(builddir)` to then find the generated file.

Makefile.am:

```
dist_noinst_DATA = whatever.swig

whatever.cpp: whatever.swig
    swig -c++ -php $^

whatever_includer.cpp: whatever.cpp

myprogram_SOURCES = ... whatever_includer.cpp
myprogram_CPPFLAGS = ... -I$(builddir)

clean-local::
    rm -f $(builddir)/whatever.cpp
```

whatever_includer.cpp:

```
#include "whatever.cpp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you want to keep `$srcdir` readonly, so that if for instance the source is distributed unpacked on a CDROM, you can still run `/.../configure` from some other part of the file-system.

However if you are using SWIG to generate source code for a wrapper library, you probably want to distribute that SWIG-generated code as well so that your users do not need to install SWIG to compile your code.  Then you have indeed a choice: you can decide that the SWIG-generated code should end in `$builddir` (it's OK: `make dist` will collect it there and include it in the tarball), or you could decide to output SWIG-generated code in `$srcdir` since it is really a source from the point of view of the distributed package.  An advantage of keeping it in `$srcdir` is that when `make distcheck` attempts to build your package from a read-only source directory, it will fail on any attempt to call SWIG to regenerate the wrapper source.  If you have your wrapper source in `$builddir`, you might not notice you have some broken rule that cause SWIG to be run on the user's host; by generating in `$srcdir` you ensure that SWIG is not needed by your users.

So my preference is to output SWIG wrapper sources in `$srcdir`.  [My setup](http://git.lrde.epita.fr/?p=spot.git;a=blob;f=wrap/python/Makefile.am;h=6a4326865055c97af9b423b8176e4c6eed7d2d99;hb=9ed2d7a1dce605271835352a1fc711d19d7c0c97) for Python wrappers looks as follows:

```
EXTRA_DIST = spot.i
python_PYTHON = $(srcdir)/spot.py    # _PYTHON is distributed by default
pyexec_LTLIBRARIES = _spot.la

MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = $(srcdir)/spot_wrap.cxx $(srcdir)/spot.py

_spot_la_SOURCES = $(srcdir)/spot_wrap.cxx $(srcdir)/spot_wrap.h
_spot_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -module
_spot_la_LIBADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libspot.la

$(srcdir)/spot_wrap.cxx: $(srcdir)/spot.i
        $(SWIG) -c++ -python -I$(srcdir) -I$(top_srcdir)/src $(srcdir)/spot.i

# Handle the multi-file output of SWIG.
$(srcdir)/spot.py: $(srcdir)/spot.i
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) spot_wrap.cxx
```

Note that I use `$(srcdir)` for all targets, [because of limitations of the `VPATH` feature on various flavors of `make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Make-Target-Lookup.html).  My setup to deal with the multiple files output by SWIG [could be improved](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html), but as these rules are not run by users and it has never caused me any problem, I do not bother.