# add #define when a specific flag is used

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries, autotools

I want to add a `#define FOO` code in an header file with autotools when I used a specific flag.

The project I have creates a static library using header to use inline functions for example. If I use the -D option, It will be used at the creation time but I'll have to add it at each compilation using this library which is what I want to avoid.

How can I perform this?

Comment: "Since it's on a header in order to create a static library, I cannot use the -D option." This sentence doesn't parse. Can you explain in more detail why you can't use -D?

Comment: @n.m. The project I have creates a static library using header to use inline functions for example. If I use the -D option, It will be used at the creation time but I'll have to add it at each compilation using this library which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: This is a much better explanation.

Comment: @n.m. I edited the question `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to generate the required header file from the pre-existing file. The following shell command would do the trick:

```
(echo "#define FOO" ; cat myheader_pregen.hpp) > myheader.hpp
```

You can incorporate the above as a script into autotools with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284918/how-to-generate-a-source-file-when-building-using-autotools)

Comment: Doesn't autoconf generate config.h for you? It seems to be the place to stick such #defines in.